# Считывание хеш-таблицы,построенной методом цепочек переполнения,в файл

Tags: delphi, хеширование

Здравствуйте, во время работы над курсовой возникла следующая проблема.

Я создал хеш-таблицу, разрешил проблему коллизий при помощи цепочек переполнения и начал работу над считыванием этой таблицы в файл. При первом запуске программы (т.е., когда файл не создан) файл, естественно, создается и добавление записей и поиск работают нормально. Затем я сохраняю свою хеш-таблицу при помощи `Write(base,HashTable[i])`, где `base` - переменная файла. Но при повторном открытии файла, вместо моих цепочек переполнения у меня стоит один 0 в каждой строке массива, где была цепочка. При этом программа часто крашится с ошибкой - `Read of Adress`.

Вопрос - при считывании данных массива, каждый элемент которого является однонаправленным списком (т.е цепочкой переполнения), в файл, нужно ли мне проходиться по каждому элементу однонаправленного списка каждой строки массива, или считывание и запись в файл верны, но ошибка в другом месте?

Процедура сохранения в файл

```
procedure SaveTheChange(HashTable:array of ListFl);
var i:integer;
begin
    assignfile(base,'base.txt');
    rewrite(base);
    for i:=1 to 10 do
    begin
        Write(base,HashTable[i]);
    end;
    Writeln('Изменения в файле успешно сохранены.');
    closefile(base);
end;
```

Процедура считывания из файла:

```
procedure mainFileOpen;
var i,j:integer;
begin
    i:=1;
    if fileExists('base.txt')
    then
    begin
        reset(base);
        While not Eof (base) do
        begin
            Read(base,HashTable[i]);
            Inc(i);
        end;
        closefile(base);
        Writeln(' Файл успешно считан.');
    end
    else
    begin
        Rewrite(base);
        Writeln(' Файл успешно создан.');
        Closefile(base);
    end;
end;

type
    Node=^Link;
    Link=record
        Key:String;
        Data:String;
        Cost:Integer;
        Next:Node;
    end;

    ListFL=record //тип,описывающий каждый элемент массива(однонаправленный список)
    First,Last:Nod e; // первый и последний элементы однонаправленного списка
    Str:String[255]; // каждый элемент списка
end;
var
    base: file of ListFl;
    HashTable:Array [0..HashSize] of ListFL; // массив для хэш-таблицы
```

Comment: Добавте ваш код или его часть, где у вас возникли трудности - [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). И добавте метку ЯП.

Comment: Добавил код процедур считывания и записи + типы, используемые в программе

Comment: Не хватает ещё метки яп, и формат кода, мягко сказать, желает улучшения.

Comment: Прошу прощения,но не могу найти метку яп среди предложенных,а персональные метки  я объявлять не могу на данных момент :)
Что конкретно Вас не устраивает в формате моего кода?

Comment: И какого языка здесь не хватает?

Comment: понял,исправлено

Comment: По поводу формата я затрудняюсь вам ответить - что мня не устраивает в формате кода, который просто не отформатирован . Отступ один символ для читаемости маловато, да и тот не соблюдается. Лучше включите в вашем иде авто формат.

Comment: Извините, конечно, но лучше бы Вы не на формат кода смотрели(который,кстати,может быть разным),а помогли бы с решением поставленной задачи,а именно: при считывании массива в файл, нужно ли мне проходить по каждому однонаправленному списку каждой строки массива или достаточно указать считывание только строки массива, как это сделано в моем примере.

Comment: вы точно на делфи пишите а не на турбо-паскале 7?

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужно.

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь записать в файл, а потом и считать, указатели. При чтении память по этим адресам не содержат те данные, которые вы ожидаете, а может и вообще не принадлежать вашей программе.

PS "программа часто крашится с ошибкой - `Read of Address`" - это верный признак того, что вы не поняли как работать с указателями.

Comment: Добавлю. Я бы в файле хранил не таблицу, а данные. При считывании из файла просто на лету создавал бы новую таблицу. Это поможет избежать проблем при смене функции хэша, при объединении нескольких таблиц и т.п. К тому же файл станет чуточку меньше.

Comment: @VladChapl, зависит от задачи. Если пишется что-то на подобие базы данных, то имеет смысл хранить цепочки сразу в записи. Я бы сохранял их как номер элемента в массиве HashTable, да и вообще обошелся бы без указателей.

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что там пишут в файл? пишут `ListFL` структура которого вообще приведена в вопросе